# $12$ Rolls of a dice: Probability of obtaining each face exactly 2 times.

Tags: probability

I was wondering about the situation in the title... would it be $(1/6)^{12}12!\approx 0.22? $ It seems a large number for an event that doesn't seem very probable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, that is too high.

You need to roll each number exactly two times in any order.

The number of permutations of 6 pairs is:  $12!/2!^6$

So the required probability is: $\dfrac{12!}{2!^6}\times\dfrac 1 {6^{12}} \approx 0.0034\ldots$